# syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end ( help me )!

Tags: ruby

got this error but cant figure out where i need to put an end.

```
test/test1:54: class definition in method body
test/test1:79: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end



class Code
  attr_reader :pegs

  def initialize(pegs)
    @@pegs_key = { "R" => :red,"G" => :green,"B" => :blue,"Y" => :yellow,
      "O" => :orange,"P" => :purple }
    @pegs = pegs
  end

  class << self
    def random
      rand_pegs_set = []
      4.times { rand_pegs_set << @@pegs_Key.values.sample }
      Code.new(rand_pegs_set)
    end

    def parse(str)
      str = string.split("")
      pegs_set = []
      str.each do |letter|
        if @@pegs_key.has_key?(letter.upcase)
          pegs_set << @@pegs_key[letter.upcase]
        else
          raise "Incorrect colors"
        end
      end
      Code.new(pegs_set)
    end
  end

  def exact_matches(guess)
    matches = 0
    pegs_set.each_with_index { |color,i| matches += 1 if self[i] == color  }
    matches
  end

  def color_counter
    counter = Hash.new(0)
    @pegs.each { |color| counter[color] += 1 }
    counter
  end

    def near_matches(guess)
      matches = 0
      code_counter = self.color_counter
      guess.color_counter.each do |color,count|
        if code_counter.has_key?(color)
          if code_counter[color] > count ? matches += count : matches += code_counter[color]
        end
      matches - self.exact_matches(guess)
    end
end

class Game
  attr_reader :secret_code

  def initialize(secret_code = Code.random)
    @secret_code = secret_code
  end

  def play
    10.times do
      puts "Enter your guess"
      guess = Code.parse(gets.chomp)
      if guess == @secret_code
        puts "Great Job! you got it"
        break
      end
      show_matches(guess)
    end
  end

  def show_matches(guess)
    exact_matches = @secret_code.exact_matches(guess)
    near_matches = @secret_code.near_matches(guess)
    puts "#{exact_matches} were exactly right"
    puts "#{near_matches} were nearly a match"
  end
end
```

Comment: Looks like `guess.color_counter.each do` is not terminated; also, `if code_counter[color] > count ? matches += count : matches += code_counter[color]` probably doesn't do what you think

Comment: I add an end after "matches - self.exact_matches(guess)" and that got rid of the first error but the test/test1:79: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end still there.         for the if else one liner, I want to take whichever value is lower and add it to "matches"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make

```
if code_counter[color] > count ? matches += count : matches += code_counter[color]
```

so

```
matches += (code_counter[color] > count ?  count : code_counter[color])
```